# Is > 5000MB/s normal for a 1TB 7200RPM HDD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, task-manager

so I decided to do a full scan with windows defender and am really confused as to why the hard-drive exceeded its limit during the scan(except if 200MB/s isn't the maximum read-write limit), I got upto 5GB/s, should that not be impossible with a 7200RPM HDD?

`
[image: my hard-drive]

How it all started:

`> 200MB/s`
[image]

`> 800MB/s`
[image]

`> 2000MB/s`
[image]

`> 4500MB/s`
[image]

`> 5000MB/s`
[image]

Comment: Since when does one trust Windows metrics ?

Comment: >5000MB is faster even than SATA-III which maxes at 300MB/s. Only way to know is to look at the resource monitor. The metrics in task manager is total use on all disks. Maybe your mainboard has a hdd cache? Or some other disk is used as scratch by the AV? (I've deleted my earlier answer since it is not correct). Without looking at the read/write metrics of the single threads in resource monitor, it's difficult to know what's going on